# High chart - stacked bar chat: How to add median in stacked bar chart type

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular7

[image]

I'm trying to add a median(vertical bar) In the middle of all bars, How can I add this median using CSS dynamically based on the series added.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a best approach to achieve it is by using below functionality which calculates and adds plotLine to the chart.

```
events: {
  load() {
    let chart = this,
      sum = 0,
      i = 0,
      medianValue;

    chart.series.forEach(s => {
      s.points.forEach(p => {
        sum += p.y
        i++;
      })
    })

    medianValue = sum / i;

    chart.yAxis[0].update({
      plotLines: [{
        value: medianValue,
        color: 'red',
        width: 10
      }]
    })
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u8a4so3r/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update